# Cups - libcups.so load failure in Debian unstable

Tags: linux, debian, printing, cups

I have a Star TSP700II thermal printer connected via USB.

When I try to print a test page in CUPS web interface I get these 2 errors in CUPS log:

```
E [23/Jul/2021:17:37:03 +0100] [Job 27] libcups.so load failure
E [23/Jul/2021:17:37:03 +0100] [Job 27] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
```

I'm on Debian Unstable, recently updated.
I have the package `libcups2` installed.

Comment: `libcups.so` is provided by **libcups2-dev**   https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcups.so  ...... → →  https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libcups2-dev/filelist ← You can also use `apt-file search libcups.so` to decide the package name.